# CVXPY doesn't terminate (with CVXOPT as solver)

Tags: python, cvxpy, cvxopt

We are using CVXPY with CVXOPT as solver (and `cvx.ROBUST_KKTSOLVER` as KKT solver) as part of a change-point detection approach.

In some cases, the call to `Problem.solve()` doesn't terminate. We cannot deterministically reproduce the problem as sometimes it would return and sometimes (very rarely) it wouldn't, for the same data.

Is there some recipe on how to terminate the solver if it doesn't return within a certain time? Is there an argument for that? (We haven't found it in the documentation.)

Just to give some context, we call the solver like that

```
w = cvx.Variable((_degree + 1 + dimensions, 1))
objective = cvx.Minimize(cvx.norm(A * w - Y, _regression_norm) ** _regression_norm + _penalty * cvx.norm(w[_degree + 1:], _basis_norm) ** _basis_norm)
constraints = []
prob = cvx.Problem(objective, constraints)
optimal_value = prob.solve(solver='CVXOPT', kktsolver=cvx.ROBUST_KKTSOLVER, verbose=True)
```

Comment: Afaik there is nothing like that in cvxopt. You might want to go for an iteration limit then which is supported in cvxopt and cvxpy should blindly pass the parameter too. But as the question is presented, there is so much left open: for example why it won't terminate for you as there will already be an upper iteration limit. Other potential questions: why is it undeterministic after all and what was done to debug this (e.g. BLAS-backend threads=1; if still undet something is broken!). Why you would want to use a general-purpose IPM alg for unconstraint (ML-like) opt? Why not (L)-BFGS and co.?